# IBM Watson Speech to Text with diarization, language dropdown selector not working

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

I have downloaded and trying to check the new added feature of Speaker Diarization. Since it has some limitation that it will work only with language models (en-US_NarrowbandModel, es-ES_NarrowbandModel, ja-JP_NarrowbandModel), I am trying to change the drop down. But it's not changing and remain fixed at "US Broadband Model (16KHz)".
Please let me know in case I am doing any thing wrong.
After downloading the source code, I did "npm install" and run the server "npm start", then from Firefox "http://localhost:3000/" it's working correctly. But, after deployment in Bluemix, the language selector is not working. The screen comes correctly but language model is not changing. I am not able to select language models other than "US Broadband Model (16KHz)".
Please advice if I am doing anything wrong.

[Note: The previous version (without Speaker Diarization feature) downloaded and it work correctly i.e. the screen comes correctly as well as language model is changing.]

Answer (score 0):

Also answered on DeveloperWorks Answers - https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/337891/ibm-watson-speech-to-text-with-diarization-languag.html

I think, based on your post that you have downloaded and modified a sample application. When you run the modified application locally your changes take effect, but when you deploy to bluemix they don't. In which case you need to work out what is different. Without seeing your modifications everything else is speculation.

Since your modified code would be browser side I suspect that they are not the same application as you would be running the code in the same browser. As your changes would be browser side, open up a developer view, and check the source on the page, to verify that your modified code is being returned. If isn't then you need to check how, where and what you are trying to deploy.

If you do see your modified code being returned then you will need to step through it to work out why it isn't being invoked correctly, possibly because of the side effect of other bluemix only scripts being invoked on the page.